# Android: Display a .gif from the internet

Tags: java, android, inputstream, gif, movie

I know that, in Android, it's possible to store .gifs in Movie objects and then manipulate the frame with setTime(). And when I try to display a .gif from a resource, it works fine.

Unfortunately, displaying a .gif from a URL is much less successful. Here is the relevant code:

```
    public void setMovieURL(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(fetch(url));
    }

    private static InputStream getStreamFromURL(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException { 
        return fetch(url);
    }

    public static InputStream fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        InputStream content = url.openStream();
        return content;
    }
```

Movie is set to a non-null value, but its height, width, and duration are all 0. An IOException is triggered in InputStream (because reset() is called), but it is also caught within InputStream. That may or may not be relevant.

I'm don't understand why that doesn't work. I'm at my wits end, and my alternatives are downloading the file and saving it, or dealing with byte arrays.

Comment: have you tried gifs from different locations on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

The same situation happens even when reading gif from file in internal storage(not from resources).
The way to solve it - download to byte[], and use ByteArrayInputStream to init movie.